# Два QLabel в одной ячейке QTableWidget имеют неправильный размер

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qlayout, qlabel

Есть такой код:

```
    ...

        cell_widget = QWidget()
        cell_widget.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        label_1 = QLabel()
        label_1.setPixmap(QPixmap('upd.gif'))
        label_1.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')

        label_2 = QLabel()
        label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap('del.gif'))

        layout.addWidget(label_1)
        layout.addWidget(label_2)
        cell_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(1,1, cell_widget)
    ...
```

---

В ячейке два виджета `QLabel` с рисунками, рисунки обычные **`.gif`** размером **`16x16`**.

Проблема в том, что рисунки немного обрезаны сверху и снизу. 
И еще желательно их как-нибудь растянуть на всю высоту ячейки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пробовал так:

```
QPixmap('upd.gif').scaledToHeight(24))
```

и так

```
label_1.setGeometry(25, 25, 25, 25)
```

не получается.

Comment: пробовали [`label_1.setFixedSize(25, 25, 25, 25)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize) ?

Comment: попробовал - вообще вылетает программа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Qt.png"))
        self.setWindowIcon(self.style().standardIcon(getattr(QStyle, "SP_TitleBarMenuButton")))
        self.setWindowTitle("Два QLabel в ячейке.")
        self.resize(300, 200)

        conLayout        = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget )

        cell_widget = QWidget()
        cell_widget.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;')
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 0)      #+++

        label_1 = QLabel()  
        label_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        label_1.setPixmap(QPixmap('upd.png').scaled(16, 16, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        label_1.setStyleSheet('border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: red;')
        label_1.setFixedHeight(20)                 #+++

        label_2 = QLabel()
        label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap('del.png').scaled(16, 16, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        label_2.setFixedHeight(20)                 #+++

        layout.addWidget(label_1)
        layout.addWidget(label_2)
        cell_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(1,1, cell_widget)

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(QIcon("del.png"), "del.png")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, newItem ) 
        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(QIcon("upd.png"), "upd.png")
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, newItem )  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо вам, очень подробный код. Про QHBoxLayout я и забыл с этой кучей виджетов

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`setScaledContents(bool)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) чтобы растянуть картинку на весь виджет

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('1.png'))
        label_1.setScaledContents(True)

        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('2.png'))
        label_2.setScaledContents(True)

        layout.addWidget(label_1)
        layout.addWidget(label_2)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое